# How do I customize the MySite page to not show empty optional fields?

Tags: my-site

I need to customize the MySite page in such a way that it should display the phone number label only if it has a value. Otherwise the phone number label should not display on the MySite page.

Any ideas on how to do this? All the MySite information comes from the user profile.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior for both 2007 and 2010, so I would take a look at one of the profiles and make sure that there isn't a value in there, even if it is just a blank space.